# How to add transparent background image over the whole page in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, background, background-image

I'm trying to put the background image over the whole page. Also the background should cover the Material Data Table. 
What is the best way to do it?
The background should also be transparent, so that you can read the content of the table.

Following the code of adding the background image:
HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <img src="assets/{{img_source}}" alt="img_source" title="img_source" width="25%" height="100%"> // not important
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <app-coffee-information></app-coffee-information>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  height: 45em;
  background-size: cover;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url('../assets/Unknown.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

[image]

When changing the height to: `height: 100%;` it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a div with class="modal" should make the trick

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    opacity:.5;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image: url('../assets/Unknown.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This covers the whole page. But still: How do I cover the material data table? The table still looks the same as in my question.

Comment: I supouse is change the z-index, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your CSS.
change

```
.image{
height: 45rem
...
}
```

to

```
.image{
height: 100%
...
}
```

Comment: try removing the width and height attributes

Comment: I did. It looks the same as with height: 100%.